# How to add to a previous JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have changed the code, so it might be a bit simpler to explain, and is now the initial problem I was trying to solve. I create a JLabel at first and I am then trying to update the text contained within it, by adding a new line and then adding more text. I have taken a look at similar questions, but the solutions did not help. This is for a timetable application.

```
private void createAndShowGUI(String [] lessons) {

...

Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
...

label1 = new JLabel("");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(label1, c);

for(int i=0; i<lessons.length; i++) {
        String format = lessons[i];
        String [] t = format.split(",");
        if (t[0].equals("1")) {
            if (t[1].equals("1")) {
                label1.setText(label1.getText() + "lecture: " + t[3] + " unit: " + t[4] + " room: " + t[2]);

...
```

Now, my input stays the same if I do not change the variables that are written else where. My current input is lessons[0] = "1,1,1,taqi,maths,bob", lessons[1] = "1,1,2,john,physics,jim" and there are a few others, but they are not relevant as they all end up in the same situation.

Within the label1.setText, I am trying to add a new line between **label1.getText()** and **"lecture: "**. So that when I run my code, I have a lecture, unit and room, and below I have another lecture, unit and room. Now for a clearer picture of my output, t[0] is the Day of the lecture and t[1] is the Time of the lecture. I am trying to display multiple lessons in different rooms on the same period and day.

Comment: For better help sooner post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. Include an image or ascii art of how the output should look like if needed

Comment: I think I havent understood your error. Is it hanging ? Are you getting an error message ? When not, how does the result look ? Is the html followed ?

Comment: I realised my question was not clear, I have updated it, hopefully it makes more sense. And no, I do not get an error message, it compiles and runs, but I only get one line in the JPanel, when there at least should be two.

Comment: Indeed your question is clearer, it's still not clear enough. A [mcve] might be of better help. :)

Comment: `label2.setText(label1.getText() + "text u want to append");`?

Comment: Your constraints preclude seeing the second line.

Comment: @IvanPronin I've updated my question, so it might be a bit more clearer as what I want to mean.

Comment: @trashgod which second line are you referring, sorry.

Comment: I was commenting on the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43768365/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JLabel doesn't recognize new line characters. The text is displayed on a single line and the new line character is ignored.

You can use HTML in a JLabel:

```
label.setText("<html>line1<br>line2</html");
```

Or you can use a JTextArea and append multiple lines of text:

```
textArea.append("\nline2");
```

Comment: For some reason when I append my code to look like `label1.setText("<html>" + label1.getText() + "<br>lecture: " + t[3] + " unit: " + t[4] + " room: " + t[2] + "</html>");`, it shows one line, instead of the previous, which was lines going off into other boxes, but now there are no lines beneath the first line. I was thinking if it was possibly to do with variable 'constraint c'?

Answer (score 0):

I was not correctly using the HTML code. I found that I had to keep the `"<html>"` at the very beginning of the text input (i.e. the initial input into the JPanel) even if I added more text to it later on, and `"</html>"` right at the end of the string. `"<br>"` can be used anywhere within the string.

Amended code:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html>");

...

for(int i=0; i<lessons.length; i++) {
        String format = lessons[i];
        String [] t = format.split(",");
        if (t[0].equals("1")) {
            if (t[1].equals("1")) {
                label1.setText(label1.getText() + "lecture: " + t[3] + " unit: " + t[4] + " room: " + t[2] + "<br>");

                ...
            }
        }
} 
label1.setText(label1.getText() + "</html>");
```

Comment: I initially kept looping <html>, </html> within the text input at random positions. Hence my error.